# Inconsistency between reputation and badges earned "today" in user profile popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, profile-popup

> [image]

I'm pretty sure neither of the badges is awarded for *0 reputation gained today*. The badges were actually awarded Dec 31, so the *earned today* line is wrong.

> [image]

---

Apparently *earned today* looks up badges in the last 24 hours, while the *today* column above it uses UTC days. Otherwise, this wouldn't make sense (saw *Revival* badge):

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a lot of users don't earn badges that frequently, we changed the text to read "recent badges:" and extended the time since earning a badge to four days (up from one day).